# Running Flask from Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, flask

Am trying to run a basic Flask code and run a html file from the flask. And am doing this on Jupyter Lab!!!
The actual problem is that, the localhost isn't running the html code. When i try to run the code, i expect it to show "Welcome" on my browser screen. But it's not showing up.

Here's the flask code.

```
from flask import Flask,request,render_template,jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/") def hello():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':

   from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
     run_simple('localhost', 9000, app)
```

'''

Here's the HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>WELCOME</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

'''

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make an effort on your presentation : no ">" when copy pasting code, and grammar. Try to be specific, here, my first question is: what is your problem? Is there anything running on your localhost:9000? Do you see an error somewhere if so, which one?

Comment: All good, what's your problem with the code here , can you be more specific?

Comment: Okay, the actual problem is that, the localhost isn't running the html code. When i try to run the code, i expect it to show "Welcome" on my browser screen. But it's not showing up.